# Post picture to facebook page/feed using codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

Yes, I know there are a lot of issues related to this topic but mine issue is not solved from those.
what I want is to post the picture and the little description below the picture and link below the picture as shown in the picture.

[image]

But I get is shown in the picture below.

[image]

My code is shown below.

```
function facebook($insert_id)
{
    $title=$this->db->query("select NewsTitle_en, image from news where id=$insert_id")->row();

    $image=$title->image;
    $pawan="<img src='127.0.0.1/nra1.2/uploads/docs/".$image."'>";
    $title=$title->NewsTitle_en;
    $id=$this->Encryption->encode($insert_id);
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
         'app_id' => '506003489738148',
         'app_secret' => 'af7afbed37636506be3fe69968a53007',
         'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
         ]);

        $linkData = [
          'link' => 'http://127.0.0.1/nra1.2/news/details/'.$id,
         'message' => $title.("\r\n").$pawan,
         // 'image' =>$image
        ];
         $pageAccessToken ='EAAHMNR5CzaQBADXO0fO7SoyZCVJ0niICyoWSCdopqZB8dZAiJNh0zFkL7YA0p6vg6YTykU968CbOYJNfV7bytXeHzdWmtKh2weLZBYNXTZBVZCOtaGcTMoeZBlgaYycjGLi1QnugcC2yZAme4cgJnc6n6X4njm7LEUY2MZC2l2xZBoZBdcOH0QxfhXieSClqQZBfVZCntinST5hGiZCwZDZD';

        try {
         $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, $pageAccessToken);
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
         echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
         exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
         echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
         exit;
        }
          $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you seriously trying to post a localhost url? facebook cannot access your local server, and no other user can either.

Comment: In codeigniter 3 > you need to set your base url in config.php if you have ip in url some images / links etc will not work. Also this img() html helper better I think for php http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html#img